# Interesting output by iteration

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Explanation of why the garbage happens & number of garbage that occur.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;

    for(int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        v1.push_back(i);

    for(int i=11 ; i <= 20 ; i++)
        v2.push_back(i);

    for(vector<int>::iterator it = v1.begin() ; it != v2.end() ; it++)
        cout << *it << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5gBIizwsY0

Comment: What would be interesting is that you explain what you _expect_ your code to do, and why.

Comment: You should format your code by putting spaces at the appropriate places so it will be more readable. That way it will be much easier to find bugs.

Comment: That's better. Even if it takes slightly more time to type formatted code you'll be paid off sooner or later.

Answer (score 6):

you iterate over vector v1 and prove the iterator against v2.end.
that's wrong. correction:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v1.begin() ; it != v1.end() ; it++)
     cout << *it << " ";
```

Comment: You are mistaken........... that's why i put it..... It should provide error..... bt at first it show the element of v1 then some garbage and again it show v2......... My ques is why it show like this ...........and after debugging it's clear now.....